# How do I look for more than one ID

Tags: php, operators

all am using this bit of PHP for a pdf print and was wondering if anyone could help me? I am looking to remove The Ids called Flights & Location at the moment it only works with just Finding and removing the location

Please see the snippet below:

```
foreach( $tabs as $tab ) {
  if(isset($_GET['type']) && $tab['id'] == 'location'){
  }else{
    $html .= '<tr><td  style="padding-top:15px; padding-bottom:15px; text-align:center; background:#b7b7b7;">';
    $html .= '<h5>' . $tab['title'] . '</h5>';
    $html .= '</td></tr>';
    $html .= '<tr><td  style="padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:20px; text-align:center;">';
    $html .= '<p>' . wpautop($tab['content']) . '</p>';
    $html .= '</td></tr>';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add to the IF statement

```
if(isset($_GET['type']) && ($tab['id'] == 'location' || $tab['id'] == 'flights') ){
// note the brackets       ^                                                   ^
```

But remember when mixing AND and OR its always good to bracket according to what you intend or things get a little odd

Comment: Hi, Riggs if I wanted to add one more if would it be as simple as adding || $tab['id'] == 'extras' within the brackets?

Comment: You mean `if(isset($_GET['type']) && ($tab['id'] == 'location' || $tab['id'] == 'flights' || $tab['id'] == 'Somthingelse' ) ){`